# How to internationalize iOS common plist resource file not "info.plist"?

Tags: ios, plist

I found many articles show me how to use especial key Apple give us like "NSCameraUsageDescription" to internationalize the info.plist, but I can't find the way to internationalize common plist resource file. Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make almost any file localised in Xcode.
But you will you will not be able to do it in the way Apple does with the `info.plist`.

If you select your custom plist file, you will see an option in the property inspector to `localize...` the file.
If you click this button, Xcode will create copies of the per localisation.

Comment: This means that I need to manually modify every copy file. How terrible! Thank you anyway.

Comment: Yes, that is a drawback, you could instead of storing the text in the plist have the key of the translation in the plist file.